# Is it okay for my boss to answer my personal and/or work cell without permission?

Tags: professionalism

I go between my desk and the warehouse throughout the day and will leave my personal cell and work cell at my desk. Is it okay for my boss to answer either cell?

Comment: Do you leave your phone on silent mode when you leave? Or do you leave it out in plain sight with a loud ringing sound when someone calls? Did you tell anyone "don't answer my phone" or did you leave it out within reach of anyone and assume that no one will think about answering it if it starts to ring?

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/2003-07-04

Comment: **Comments deleted**: Please don't use comments for debate or discussion.  Comments are intended to help a poster improve a post or to seek clarification.  Instead, please use [chat].  See [What comments are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean "should I ask my boss to answer my phone?", "should I switch my phone off when I can't answer it?", "should I give my boss permission to answer my phone, just in case they want to?", or "should my boss answer my phone even though I don't want him to speak to my callers?"  Please give some context: do you expect calls from recruiters, from customers, or urgent personal messages from your family. Are your calls so urgent that you need your boss to answer, or do you expect your calls to be so private that you don't want your boss to know who called?

Comment: The issue I don't really see being addressed here is BYOD (Bring Your Own Device). It sounds like this may not be a BYOD situation, but the fact is that many businesses embrace BYOD, which means that you use your personal mobile device for work. This blurs lines, obviously, and depending on company policies I may choose not to do that. Some people work for companies with policies which state that if the device touches the company network at all, the company has the right to analyze ALL of the data on the device. In such a situation, I would maintain a strict separation.

Answer (score 192):

> I go between my desk and the warehouse throughout the day and will leave my personal cell and work cell at my desk. Is it okay for my boss to answer either cell?

I think you are asking the wrong question. The obvious naive answer is **no** it's not ok.

But why is your boss even in the position to answer either your private *or* your work cell phone?

Your private cell phone is private. It should never be on your desk and it should never make a sound that can be heard by your colleagues. Put it in your pocket, put it in a drawer or leave it at home. Set it to vibrate or silent mode. **Don't** leave it ringing on your desk. That's very annoying.

Your work cell phone should never be unattended at your desk. Well, maybe if you take a break in the restroom, but that's it. If your company had wanted you to have a phone at your desk only, they would have installed such a phone. But they gave you a mobile phone. Leaving it at your desk on purpose is not only annoying all your coworkers when it rings, but probably directly against the intention of giving you a mobile phone in the first place. The point of a mobile phone is to be able to reach you while you are not at your desk. So when it does ring at your desk, you boss can only assume it's a call for work and you forgot your phone. So yes, he has a good reason to answer it, *he is covering for you*.

So the bottom line is: your private phone should be silent somewhere inaccessible to your boss, while your work phone should be on you, where you can answer it. Asking your boss to stop answering either phone will only point out that you fail to handle your cell phones correctly. Instead, take care of your phones from now on.

Comment: I think "never make a sound" is getting a bit overboard. Like all things its a balance. The term I see frequently used is "reasonable personal use," so if your wife calls once to see what you want from the store its fine, but if you're texting with your best friend all day its not.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg If talking to one's wife is ok is up to the parties of the employment contract. However, even if it is, to get a call from your wife it's not necessary for your phone to disturb others. Put it in your pocket and turn vibration on. No need for loud or repeated ringing noises.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I don't think "never make a sound" is overboard. The only reason I would say it's okay to have it off vibrate is if you're doing something that doesn't allow you to have it on your person, for example you're on some scaffolding and answering it at that time would be dangerous, but you need to know it's going off. This environment is *probably* loud enough anyway that it won't cause a distraction. The other is for emergency notifications (when our servers go down, our phone goes bonkers) but that's INTENDED to be annoying and noticible. Other than that, turn the damn thing down.

Comment: Another alternative is to put on a ringtone that is chosen to be as non-invasive as possible.  Not that it could never get annoying, but "Jesu, Joy of Man's Desiring" (which I use personally) isn't as jarring as, say, "Highway to Hell" if you're working out some algorithm in your head and hear it from your cellmate's desk.

Comment: In jobs where I've had a company mobile phone, it's been so that I can be contacted if I'm travelling away from my base, not if I'm away from my desk but somewhere on the premises. So it would be totally fine to leave the phone on my desk.

Comment: @BobRodes That is completely subjective. What one person finds soothing and noninvasive, another can find grating and disturbing beyond measure.

Comment: @BobRodes While I personally think that it's good to be respectful in regards to your ring tone, a ring tone is *meant* to be annoying enough that people notice it. So picking one that is not annoying enough to notice it is a fools errand. It can only be one thing at a time, either noticeable or not noticeable. To be noticeable *only for you*, vibration might be a good choice.

Comment: @corsiKa: one way to look at this is that if the phone call is sufficiently important and urgent that the phone needs to ring, then it's sufficiently important and urgent that the phone's owner should be there to hear/answer it. The exact nature and frequency of those calls is up for negotiation. The basic equation remains that if you can't hear your own phone there's no point it ringing. And OK, maybe you're up a ladder and the phone ringing is your cue to come down and fix the servers, but the questioner doesn't have that excuse, they're asking about when they're in the warehouse...

Answer (score 36):

I do not think it is really at all ethical for your boss to be answering your personal cell phone. The company cell phone may be a different matter though depending upon company policy and any set agreements between employees and the management.

Now back to that personal cell phone. If you want it left alone then, rather than having to poll on the internet for advice, use some common sense:

1. Keep it with you
2. Shut it off and lock it in a drawer
3. Place it in an employee locker if one is provided
4. Leave it at home

Comment: Set a lock code, and turn the phone off when you leave your desk. Do not tell the boss the code.

Comment: And it on vibrate, or better, silent, so that your boss can't hear it.

Comment: Your advice is not really practical. People have personal phones in order to be reachable at all times (or almost at all times). I doubt there are many people who buy a phone just to keep it at home all day or locked up in a drawer.

Comment: @RaduMurzea: the OP apparently does not want to be reachable at all times, judging from the fact that he leaves the phone on his desk when he leaves.

Comment: @StephenKolassa or he could just, not answer the phone when he doesn't want to answer the phone?

Comment: @RaduMurzea I've had a cell phone for 10 years or so, and the only times it's been physically turned on in a work office has been when I was calling out and _possibly_ when I forgot to turn it off after use. (I don't recall ever discovering that it was left on.) If I needed to be reached at work, the company phone systems always gave capability.

Comment: @user2338816: "Company phone systems" are **not** a solution for employees receiving personal calls at work. They take up somebody else's time (the receptionist/secretary/whoever) and tie up a phone that's actually supposed to be used for work-related activity. If employees want to be receiving personal calls they should do it on their own phones so that only one employee's time is taken away, rather than two employees and a company resource.

Comment: Somehow we survived before cell phones. The Internet. Computers. Electricity... They are not necessary for life to exist.

Comment: @R.. If I see people taking personal calls on their personal mobile phones, I find that unprofessional. Well, unless it is on a break. The company phone systems are a fine solution when the employee has to be reached for something personal in case of emergency, or otherwise exceptional circumstances. The real problem is people taking personal calls when they are at work, not which device they use for them.

Comment: @R.. I don't recall ever having to route an incoming/outgoing call from my desk phone through a receptionist/etc (although theoretically someone could look up the main number in an external phonebook and call in to be transfered); that's what having a direct dial number is for.

Comment: Even if the call can be routed directly without taking up another employee's time, it still ties up the employee's line that should be open for business purposes. If they're on a personal cell phone call they can hang up and answer their desk phone. If they're taking the personal call on the work phone, actual business-related calls are likely to go straight to voicemail.

Comment: @R.. There are very few circumstances when anyone **needs** to call someone at work. Company phones work fine except for employees who spend too much time on personal calls during work hours. Management should handle those employees. In 40+ yrs in corporate and small business offices, I've never seen it be discouraged though I'd accept that it happens. If it ever did, I'd be unlikely to work there.

Comment: @Sumurai8 If someone is taking personal calls at work to the point that it is a problem, then the problem is a bigger one than taking personal calls at work.  If you find taking personal calls under any circumstances to be unprofessional, then perhaps your "work-life balance" needs some attention.

Comment: @nocomprende We also survived without vaccines and modern farming techniques.  So what?  Your comment is irrelevant and unnecessary.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Maybe if you're working in a warehouse or assembly line, but in most office professions, there are no set break periods and reasonable time spent making personal calls is not considered unprofessional, at least in the US.

Comment: "`I do not think it is really at all ethical for your boss to be answering your personal cell phone.`" But, think about it from the boss's perspective. The boss is at the work place, and notices, "Oh, here's a phone ringing." Do you really think that, instead of answering it, the boss should first say "I wonder whether this is a personal cell (that doesn't even really belong here)...  While this phone is ringing, I will investigate ownership before deciding whether to answer the phone before it goes to a voicemail."  (Or do you think most people place a "PERSONAL PHONE" label on their phones?)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: "*Set a lock code, and turn the phone off when you leave your desk. Do not tell the boss the code*" -- I keep my (Android) phone locked at all times, but I don't have to enter a lock code to answer an incoming call.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's ethical. You left a noisy, disruptive device on your desk; it's entirely reasonable for your boss, or anyone else your carelessness is disturbing, to take polite steps to deal with the nuisance you have caused to your co-workers. For a work phone I cannot see any issue at all. (This assumes that your boss picked the phone up and answered in polite fashion, if he's picking up the phone and pretending to be you or answering in a "joke" fashion that's another issue).

If you don't want this to happen then switch your phone off, put it to silent and non-vibrating mode, or keep it on your person.

Comment: -1 It's never ethical to answer another persons private phone without permission. If the ringing is disturbing, it's perfectly reasonable to reject the call, but answering isn't. (For work phones it's of course a different situation)

Comment: rejecting a call is fine (but better is to mute it)
but if it ringed more than 1 time , its totally reasonable to pick it up as it can be some call going unattended, the boss is not misusing any thing kept at table or playing games in his phone, or eating his lunch, he did what a logical person will do. Its perfectly fine as per my thinking.

Comment: A minor annoyance does not justify unauthorized access to a personal computing device.

Comment: @raznagul *never ethical to answer another persons private phone* - totally wrong, if you have injuries, dead, or can't talk - it's totally ethical to answer you private phone. Also knowing that you expecting call, some important for you and knowing that you will have no access for phone some time, it's possible to answer in some cases. It's possible to answer it in cases when you calling your phone to find it, maybe you lost in in toilet and .... Think 7 times before say never. Do not reject others calls, you misrepresenting the person by doing that, by pretending to be the owner of phone.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Minor annoyance for 20 peoples, is big problem, specially if that disturbs them from work and interupts working process(like talking with clients). I hope you do not make mistakes like OP do, counting them not important.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Answering a phone is not "access to a personal computing device"; don't be so melodramatic.

Comment: @raznagul I would say that cell-phone ethics aren't sufficiently evolved to make a pronouncement of such finality on them.  After all, cell-phone *etiquette* hasn't even fully evolved yet, a fact to which this discussion attests.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It's not like going through someone's personal email.

Comment: @MolbOrg: The core problem is, that a personal phone shouldn't be left lying around at the workplace. But even if it happens, it is no excuse to invade that persons private space (at least here in central Europe). I'll give you that there are some exceptional cases (major injury, death). But all your other examples don't make sense. In that cases the person would be around to give the permission, or would have given permission beforehand.

Comment: @MolbOrg: Yes, rejecting a call does send a message and is rude, and I would only do it if there is no other option (tracking that person, setting the phone to silent). But in my opinion less rude than violation privacy.

Comment: @raznagul It's pretty fine leave belongings at work place during work time, until they do not invade others privacy by smelling and noising, here in europe-asia. If it's happening, someone will be informed about situation(depends, in phone case as fast as possible), and it is expected to not repeat errors and give apologies. Phone problem pretty rare case, all know it's annoying and most cases was mishap. Those who did't give s about, where informed twice, they did not repeated their errors. Your privacy is your concern, but my is my. Although OP have other intend, so this discus is pointless.

Comment: I consider rejecting the call acceptable, answering it is pretty close to going through someone's personal mail in my book and if repeatedly done, I'd consider legal action.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Our big American "legal action" card isn't all that powerful when played. Go ask a lawyer what action you can take for someone answering your personal cell phone, and you're likely to find that you haven't a case.  But I agree with you up to a point.  It has some aspects of going through someone's personal mail, but with the difference that the other party knows that they aren't communicating with the intended party.  But, if repeatedly done, when there's a good reason to leave it lying around (I can't think of one), then it's a pretty strong invasion of privacy.

Comment: Another method of stopping a ringing phone without invading anyone's privacy is to drop it into a bucket of water. Which would you prefer?

Comment: have none of you actually handled a cell phone? if it's ringing or vibrating you can just hit the volume-down button and silence the call. that way you're neither answering or rejecting the call, just silencing an annoying phone.

Comment: @gnasher729: at one point at work we did seriously consider getting a Faraday cage to put in the corner of the office (or fashioning one, but the company worked on mobile phones anyway so an off the shelf RF isolation box would be in character). The people who left their phones on their desks could retrieve them from there after they'd rung and been dumped in. We ruled out using the microwave since none of us wanted to be responsible for what happened if someone used it without spotting there was a phone in there too.

Answer (score 1):

**No No No No**, I personally believe its not Ok to any one to access your cell without your permission until and unless you have given any one to access your cell.

Logically it should not be the case that someone else answer your call without your permission. Because your cell is something which is to be not shared, in the same way your personal passwords are private.

In this case, if your boss sometimes answers the calls from your cell, then please keep your cell with you, at least your personal cell. Directly telling your boss that "*You don't have the right to answer calls on on my cell*", is a bad idea as it will make you appear rude in front of him and that will affect how he considers your attitude".

Adding a cell phone password will not solve your problem as you can answer a call without unlocking the phone so its my personal point of view that the best course of action is to keep your personal cell with you.

Comment: Others can use his bottle and lunch or whatever if it was that way(which is wrong )... but cellphone is different thing , if they were playing games on that I can consider it wrong, but they did right thing by answering a phone call which would have left been unattended, also it was not on silent.

Comment: Can you please put this as answer if you are sure? lets share your views to all

Comment: already jack aidley has written that's why i have not done

Comment: I don't agree with you here.  If someone's cell phone is left unattended, it isn't unethical to answer it.  After all, it could be the owner trying to find it.  It's more a matter of whether someone cares about invading your privacy or not, and even that, while rude, isn't unethical.  Unethical is dishonest, not rude. Pretending to be someone you're not is unethical, for example answering texts on someone else's phone as if you are the owner.  Trying to find out things about someone by answering the phone and listening to the other party without identifying yourself is unethical.

Comment: Removed the word "Ethical" from answer which was creating confusion to everyone

Comment: @BobRodes I do think it's unethical to answer someone else's personal cell phone without permission.  Unethical is not just dishonest behavior.   Disclosing your medial records without your permission is unethical, even though they are statements of facts.

Comment: @Andy re medical records: that's because there is the implied understanding that you will not do so, and therefore doing so is dishonest.  Before the information explosion, patients would not give a second thought to their medical records, and doctors would be free to use their own discretion to disclose whatever details they felt were in the patient's best interest.  Then we had businesses basing hiring decisions on medical records, banks basing loan decisions on them, etc. and we put laws and regulations into place.

Comment: Now.  You say unethical is not just dishonest.  Logically, therefore, you must also be saying that there is a set of dishonest behavior that does not meet the criteria for being unethical--a set of dishonest but ethical behavior.  Can you support your position with an example?

Comment: @BobRodes There's also an implied understanding you won't answer my personal phone without permission.  And please take a logic course; A implies B does not necessarily mean that B implies A.  My statement was that there is behavior which is unethical but not dishonest, I never said there was dishonest behavior which was ethical. If you want an example though, white lies are typically considered ethical, even though they are dishonest, because you are, for example, trying to spare someone's feelings.

Comment: @Andy So, when you are saying that unethical is not "just" dishonest, you are not saying that it is "more than" dishonest?  I thought you were, and took that to mean that ethical is a subset of dishonest.  And for the record, I don't consider white lies either ethical or honest.  Manipulation of others isn't ethical, and "trying to spare someone's feelings" is manipulation.  But that doesn't mean that I'm "right" or anything; you could be "right" as well.  Who really knows?

Comment: @BobRodes Right, dishonest is a subset of unethical behavior.  While you might not consider white lies ethic, most of polite societies disagree.

Comment: @Andy Ok, so there is also honest and unethical behavior.  I don't agree (perhaps you misspoke).  And most polite societies are responsible for most of the problems of the world.

Answer (score -8):

Place, stick big red label private, on both sides of your phone, switch it in silent mode(no vibro, no sound).

Make crystal clear for any which one is your personal phone and which one is work phone. Do it in such a way that any person without asking you, will know which one is which and will pick work phone if it is required.

Also, expect unexpected in cases if you forget someday to switch the personal phone to silent mode.

It's not ok to answer personal phone, and it's ok for you to make EVERYTHING possible such way, that no one **have** to answer your phone.

And if you didn't, then yes it's ok to answer your phone, especially thinking that you have forgotten your phone and now you are searching for it, even if caller name is pornostart69.

Best is to get rid of the bad habit of leaving phones in random places if one is sharing a workplace with other workers, no one needs to hear your laladance ringtone for 5-10 minutes when one tries to call you.